# How can I decide if switch view value was changed by user interaction or by code in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement, ibaction

I have a switch view on my UI and I'd like to handle the event when its value is changed. To perform this I've made an IBAction method to handle value changed event. So far so good.

My problem is I can't decide if change was performed by
- code (it may happen in my app)
- user interaction

How can I decide if it was changed by a user interaction or by code?

Comment: How are you checking for the switch being changed programatically? I don't think your valueChanged event will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific method that changes the switch value when it's done by code only? If so, maybe you could use that method to set a boolean/flag to check against when you need to decide/handle the event.

Comment: Yes, there is, but I thought there was a more straightforward/built in way to do it. E.g. some property like eventssource. I thought to implement it as you advise but I thought it is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

In Apple ScrollView / ScrollPages Example they have a simmilar situation:
They have to decide whether an event was self(=code) triggered, or by the user.
They simply set a variable (before programatically calling) to distinguish between this two situations.

Comment: Hmm, I thought there is a more streamlined solution.

Comment: Yeah, it does not look nice, even in apples exampel code, but as long as you cannot set a userInfo object for that action, how would one know?

Comment: Thx Alex, very kind to answer me, my dissapointment was about apple

Comment: Apple alreday has a sender object, but this sender will be th e button. In some of my other non ios application i had the need to add a "cause" info. In your case sender woud be the UI object, but cause = "programm"; In most cases one would not need such a cause.